# Java Splitting a String by parentheses

Tags: java, parentheses

If I had an equation like this:

```
(equ1)+(equ2)-sqrt(equ2)
```

How do I collect the top most parentheses only? The equations can have things like:

```
((inner equation))+((inner equation))
```

So splitting by a regex such as:

```
.split("[()]")
```

Doesn't help me

I have tried to create a for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < equation.size(); i++) {
        str = equation.get(i).toString();
        str2 = string;
        elements = str2.split("(\((?:[^()]|(?1))*\))");
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parSolver.toArray()));
    }
```

to replace `((inner equation)) + ((inner equation))` with `"Number1"+"Number2"` but i cannot do that without separating the parentheses first; any help is appreciated.

I have to note that the equation is already answered, I just need to plug it into the string by replacing the parentheses with the answer:

```
equation element 1: ""Answer"
str: ((inner equation))+ ((inner equation))
becomes: "Answer"+((inner equation))
(Repeat process)
```

One thing i also tried was trying to get the parentheses locations:

```
0,6 8,13
```

And i tried to set a substring to that value between 0,6 and 8,13. and replace it:

```
str = string.substring(0, 6);
string = string.replace(str, "Answer");
```

But something is severely wrong with the values because i did count where each parentheses is, like if '(' is at index 0 and ')' is at index 6, then why doesn't this sub-string cooperate and give me the value: `(_____)`?

The errors I encounter with that strategy are `Index out of bounds` and I can never seem to collect the right sub-string sections. Its always over the string length, even though the parentheses locations are IN the string. The iteration in the sub-string definitely doesn't start at 0 or I wouldn't have this problem.

Note: What if i could define the parentheses? like i have 2 sets, three sets, etc. Will I be able to use a regex?

Comment: Nitpick: I think you mean "term" and not "equation"

Comment: I don't think you can, for arbitrary nesting parenthesis.  (I think it's possible if you can define a maximum number of nesting parenthesis though.)  For the general case you need a parser, not regex.

Comment: So say I could, what would be the regex. I have an idea, that could work.

Comment: I recommend you check out Dijkstra's [Shunting-yard Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).  It will provide a mechanism for parsing your `infix` expressions and converting to  `postfix` for easy evaluation.

Comment: No need for it, I'm just collecting parentheses. I'm not solving anything. Example: (equ)+(equ) would turn into [X] + [X]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with a regex, since it's not a context free problem. You'd need to write your own recursive descent parser or other mechanism to be able to parse the expression into a tree and then use that.

Comment: I'm not requesting a equation parser, and neither am I refering to solving ANY equation. I simply am looking for a replacer method. So anything that are in between the top level parentheses (())+(())+sqrt() turns into [X]+[X]+sqrt[X]. I've already solved the equations.